# Error: Unsupported field type called "Text (Encrypted)

Tags: apex, formula-field, field-level-encryption

I was hoping to get some ideas on how can I go about doing this.

So I want to run a report that checks if one Encrypted field in one of our objects is empty but we cant use encrypted fields in any of the filters or anywhere.

We needed a way to check so we originally thought we could have a formula field and have a checkbox to see if it's empty if it is then check it. Unfortunately looks like Salesforce won't allow that I keep getting the `'Unsupported field type called "Text (Encrypted)'`. Is there another way of doing this?

```
Actual formula : IF(LEN(CODE__c)==0,0,1)

Error: ' You referenced an unsupported field type called "Text (Encrypted)" using the following field: CODE__c'
```

Can we use apex class to check this instead?

Comment: Can you share the formula that is causing an error?

Comment: Hi, @MohithShrivastava I have added the formula.

Comment: Is it LEN? I see LENT there

Comment: @MohithShrivastava its LEN

Comment: Please don't abuse the `[community]` tag, only add it when actually asking about the `Communities` feature.

Comment: Can you enable 'View Encrypted Data' and use a SOQL query? For example here. SELECT Code__c, FROM Account

Answer (score 0):

There are only a handful of formula functions that are supported by encrypted fields. Check the list [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_formulas.htm)

> Supported operators and functions are below

- & and + (concatenate)
- BLANKVALUE
- CASE
- HYPERLINK
- IF
- IMAGE
- ISBLANK
- ISNULL

Also carefully note below

> Formulas can return data only in text, date, or date/time formats.

For your use case, `LEN` is not supported.

A workaround could be a simple `before insert` and `before update` Apex Trigger as those will have access to the encrypted field.

Comment: I tried with ISBLANK but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you try other functions as well and see if you receive the same error?

Comment: Yup same errors

Comment: What is the return type of your formula?

Comment: Note that you can only return Text, date, or date/time. So I suggest return a text field called YES or NO

Comment: Can you show me how I can have YES OR NO  returned with this formula?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126237/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-simple-code).